# How to parse only one column with a different delimiter?

Tags: awk

I have a tab-delimited file. The last column is semicolon-delimited with unequal, long lines. I want to parse this column.

Input:

```
AA   762    8640    BB    CC     DD      EE=T;FF=C;GG=G;HHA
II   852    6547    JJ    KK     LL      MM=G;NN=P;QQ=RF
```

Desired output:

```
AA   762    8640    BB    CC     DD      EE=T    FF=C    GG=G   HHA
II   852    6547    JJ    KK     LL      MM=G    NN=P    QQ=RF
```

I could get e.g. the first three values using this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=";" } { print $1, $2, $3}' file
```

But, when I run this, it does not parse the column, and just prints the files as is:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=";" } { print $0}' file
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) approach

```
awk -F'[[:space:];]' -vOFS='\t' '{$1=$1;print}' input.txt
AA  762 8640    BB  CC  DD  EE=T    FF=C    GG=G    HHA
II  852 6547    JJ  KK  LL  MM=G    NN=P    QQ=RF
```

Comment: We can drop the `print` and do just `awk ... '{$1=$1}1' input.txt` but better clear than cryptic. `:)`

Comment: @jaypal, the explicit `print` is probably my Python roots betraying me there :-) Yes, i like it readable

Comment: @1_CR, Thank you! could you explain the what `[:space:]` specifies? Also, what is the difference between OFS and vOFS?

Comment: @user2162153, `-F'[[:space:];]'` sets the field separator to whitespace or `;` (whitespace is a tab or a space character). `-vOFS='\t'` is actually `-v OFS='\t'`. This allows passing in `OFS` via the command line rather than setting it inside the script

Comment: @1_CR, Thanks! How does `awk` understand that the word `space` signifies space-delimiter?

Comment: @user2162153, `[:space:]` is just one of several character classes that awk supports [out of the box](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_29.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{gsub(/;/,"\t",$NF)}1' file
```

```
$ cat file
AA  762 8640    BB  CC  DD  EE=T;FF=C;GG=G;HHA
II  852 6547    JJ  KK  LL  MM=G;NN=P;QQ=RF
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{gsub(/;/,"\t",$NF)}1' file
AA  762 8640    BB  CC  DD  EE=T    FF=C    GG=G    HHA
II  852 6547    JJ  KK  LL  MM=G    NN=P    QQ=RF
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tr` to replace semi-colons with tabs like this:

```
tr ";" "\t" <yourfile
```

Comment: +1. Also `tr ";" "\t" 1<>yourfile <yourfile` for in-place replacement!

Comment: @1_CR Thats pretty slick and I thought you like it readable! `:P`!!

Comment: @jaypal, it's actually quite elegant if you understand the underlying [mechanics](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87461/21233)